# How to loop in the try: exception?

Tags: python, try-catch, except

I'm extracting a gz file and its giving me a errno because in the **scraping** that I'm also doing the browser did not yet downloaded the file so i thought of doing a try, if the error comes on then i make it wait for a while and put it back in the extraction but I'm doing it wrong, not even close to be honest, I'm doing it like this :

```
    try:
     pass
    ## Download to folder and use whatever comes out
     file_downloaded = False
     while not file_downloaded:
         for file in os.listdir("tmp"):
             if file.endswith("csv.gz"):
                 fp = os.path.join('tmp', file)
                 logmsg = ("Extracting ", fp)
                 instalog.appendMessage('INFO', logmsg)
                 with gzip.open(fp, 'r') as f_in:
                     with open(newfile_path, 'wb') as f_out:
                         shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
                         file_downloaded = True
             elif file.endswith(".csv"):
                 fp = os.path.join('tmp', file)
                 logmsg = ("File was not compressed ", fp)
                 instalog.appendMessage('INFO', logmsg)
                 with open(fp, 'rb') as f_in:
                     with open(newfile_path, 'wb') as f_out:
                         shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
                         file_downloaded = True
    except IOError:
        time.sleep(2)
        pass
```

**By sugestion im doing now this**

```
for file in os.listdir("tmp"):
            file_downloaded = False
            while not file_downloaded:
                try:
                    if file.endswith("csv.gz"):
                        fp = os.path.join('tmp', file)
                        logmsg = ("Extracting ", fp)
                        instalog.appendMessage('INFO', logmsg)
                        with gzip.open(fp, 'r') as f_in:
                            with open(newfile_path, 'wb') as f_out:
                                shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
                                file_downloaded = True
                    elif file.endswith(".csv"):
                        fp = os.path.join('tmp', file)
                        logmsg = ("File was not compressed ", fp)
                        instalog.appendMessage('INFO', logmsg)
                        with open(fp, 'rb') as f_in:
                          with open(newfile_path, 'wb') as f_out:
                                shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
                                file_downloaded = True
                except IOError:
                    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how to put the exception handing inside the loop?

Comment: I want to make that attempt of downloading the gz repeat if the error errno appears but wait for a couple seconds before trying again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def unzip_gzip(source_path, destination_path):
    with gzip.open(source_path, "rb") as f_in:
        with open(destination_path, "wb") as f_out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)


def process_file(file_name):
    if file_name.endswith("csv.gz"):
        full_path = os.path.join("tmp", file)
        instalog.appendMessage("INFO", ("Extracting ", full_path))
        unzip_gzip(full_path, new_file_path)

    elif file_name.endswith(".csv"):
        full_path = os.path.join("tmp", file)
        instalog.appendMessage("INFO", ("File was not compressed ", full_path))
        shutil.copyfile(full_path, new_file_path)

    else:
        return


for file in os.listdir("tmp"):
    success = False
    while not success:
        try:
            process_file(file)
            success = True
        except IOError:
            time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I understand your code , i don't want to make a function, how can i after the try go back to the top ?

Comment: I will edit and add the code like im trying to do .